# How can I get my cout output on the console with roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does only error output appear at the console when launching a ros node from roslaunch? Also, I can I force the normal behavior, so that I can see my cout output?

For example, I wrote this in a simple node:

```
ROS_INFO("ROS_INFO");
ROS_WARN("ROS_WARN");
ROS_ERROR("ROS_ERROR");
std::cout << "cout" << std::endl;
std::cerr << "cerr" << std::endl;
```

If I call `rosrun myNode myNode`, I see the five lines. If I call `roslaunch myNodeLauncher`, I see only ROS_ERROR and std::cerr.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9473/how-can-i-get-my-cout-output-on-the-console-with-roslaunch/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your Roslaunch [XML](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node) add the following within your node tags:

```
output="screen"
```

You can always change the debug-level from [RXconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole), select the node and change the level [(rxloggerlevel)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxloggerlevel).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 27

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm not sure if you can see the std::cout when using roslaunch. To see all log messages (the one you print using ROS_INFO / ... ), you can use rxconsole.

Do you know about ROS_ERROR_STREAM / ROS_WARN_STREAM / ROS_INFO_STREAM ? It allows you to use a cout kind of syntax:

```
ROS_ERROR_STREAM("This is my index: " << i);
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5